# Changing a td within a CSS class via javascript

Tags: javascript, css

It's a fact; I just about "get by" using CSS and Javascript, and can usually find a solution to a problem ... but this has me stumped.

I have set up classes as this ...

```
 .pop_close{ outer table data here}
 .pop_close td{ outer table cell data here}
 .pop_form{ table data here}
 .pop_form td{ table cell data here}

<table class="pop_close" id="101"><tr><td>CLOSE X</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<table class="pop_form" id="102">
<tr><td>DATA HERE ....
```

Now I can set the outer table color, increase the width of the inner table and move it down the screen as I am affecting the **table** tag itself thus:

```
document.getElementById('101').style.backgroundColor='red'
document.getElementById('101').style.top=top+'px';
document.getElementById('102').style.width=width+'px';
document.getElementById('102').style.height=height+'px';
```

But how do I change the cell data of "pop_form"? (on fourth line of CSS where there is a space before the td tag) I cannot set all td's to one class / ID as there are others on the page that remain unaffected.

It's actually a pop up form where the user can specify their own outer border color beside the close button, and set a width and border style of the inner table, and then I show the result on screen. But setting the inner table border has me stumped. (And before you tell me, yes, I know it's frowned upon to nest tables, but it's easiest layout method I know!)

+++ 14th Nov update

I think I have found part of the problem.
As I explained to another user, I have a table up to the <tr> tag, then I add the rest of the table data dynamically via javascript. Having just looked at code, up to the <tr> tag, it's 'hard coded' into the HTML page, (and hidden with the visibility:hidden CSS) So JS can 'see' this, and is able to manipulate it. The inside of the table however is generated *within* the JS, so effectively it cannot see it to change it, (that's my assumption) It can still 'pull' its class data into the table as the CSS is again part of the main page, but I'm asking javascript to manipulate its own data. For sake of clarity, I show the code below:

> 

```
<span style="position:fixed;top:20px;height:100%;width:100%;visibility:hidden;pointer-events:none;z-index:10;" id="101">
<table cellspacing="0" align="center" class="pop_close" id="103">
<tr><td align="right">
<a href="javascript:void[0];" onclick="HidePop('101');" style="pointer-events:auto">CLOSE</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>
<table cellspacing="0" align="center" class="pop_form" id="102">
<!-- text appears here-->
</table>
</td></tr>
</table>
</span>
```

The above is hard coded. Then, in javasript I add:

```
 form[0]='<tr><td valign="top">'+str+'</td></tr>\\n';
form[1]='<tr><td valign="top">'+str+'<br><br>'+bot_code+'</td></tr>\\n';
form[2]='<tr><td valign="top"><img src="%prod_img%">\\n</td>\\n<td valign="top">\\n'+str+'</td>\\n</tr>\\n<tr>\\n<td colspan="2">\\n<center>\\n'+bot_code+'\\n</center>\\n</td>\\n</tr>\\n';
form[3]='<tr><td valign="top"><img src="%prod_img%">\\n</td>\\n<td valign="top" id="pf_td>\\n'+str+'<br><br>\\n<center>\\n'+bot_code+'\\n</center>\\n</td>\\n</tr>\\n';
form[4]='<tr><td valign="top">'+str+'</td>\\n<td valign="top">\\n<img src="%prod_img%">\\n</td>\\n</tr>\\n<tr>\\n<td colspan="2">\\n<center>\\n'+bot_code+'\\n</center>\\n</td>\\n</tr>\\n';
form[5]='<tr><td valign="top">'+str+'<br><br>\\n<center>\\n'+bot_code+'\\n</center>\\n</td>\\n<td valign="top">\\n<img src="%prod_img%">\\n<//td>\\n</tr>\\n';
```

It's these latter form values that I'm trying to set the border details for from data entered via a form.

Comment: I'd rather not for the simple fact I'm still just getting to grips with javascript, (I normally use PERL) so to add something I know zilch about would confound matters further. See my edited post at the top.

Comment: would you be able to post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).
also technically ids should not start with numbers - probly not the issue though

Answer (score 0):

Are there multiple nested tables, 101..102..103..10n, or it just these two?

If there are only the two, I'm curious why you wouldn't just use the ID instead of the class.

You could check out `document.getElementsByClassName()`, which creates an array of objects that have that class name.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I say, I'm no expert, and code by a "try-it-and-see-if-it-works" approach. I didn't know there was a "ClassByName" option, (and until I try it, don't know exactlt what it can do for me) There are only these two tables -one outer and one inner- and at this time, the "get by ID" option is the only one I know works. If push comes to shove, I'll give the 8 td's an ID and see if that works. (There's six form layouts the user can select from, and 1-3 td's in each. The base template is as far as "102", then I dynamically enter td's and end with &lt/table&gt;)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around the problem.

The inner <td> tag I gave a class name of "pop", (ie the ones where it says "DATA HERE")

I then used the javascript to dynamically set the width, height, background colour of the table with id of "102"

Next, I used "document.getElementById('pop').innerHTML=DATA HERE"; to 'inject' the text into the table cell. And to move the table down the screen ... I moved the whole  that holds the  tags down the screen